# Invalidating cache and all references

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I find the article titled `How Basecamp Next got to be so damn fast without using much client-side UI` from 37 signals ([here](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3112-how-basecamp-next-got-to-be-so-damn-fast-without-using-much-client-side-ui)) but couldn't understand how the cache invalidating works.

let say:

i have a `post` object in array form like this:

```
$post = array(
    'id' => 3232,
    'title' => 'Test Post'
)
```

I'am saving it in the cache with cache key named: `post-3232`. And i have a `latest posts` array like this:

```
$latest = array(
    array(
        'id' => 3232,
        'title' => 'Test Post'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3233,
        'title' => 'Test Post 1'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3234,
        'title' => 'Test Post 2'
    )
)
```

I'm saving this list in cache with the cache key: `latest-posts-140320121947`

How can my latest posts list knows if any of the posts are deleted, changed or a new post is inserted?
I can't figure out it from the article. maybe i can find some help from StackOverflow.

Comment: If you're using PHP, @cnkt, try symfony - this has had nested caching available for years, right from version 1.0. (Turning on cache visibility is awesome - you get to see real-time cache monitors on each cached block a bit like the 37 Signals picture). I've not tried Symfony 2, pretty much because 1.3 fits my needs fine - but it may also have this feature.

Comment: Symfony might be doing this but i need to know "how i can do it with my own code" because i want to learn the logic behind this implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. If you have related follow-up Qs, do post here. I could probably link to the symfony 1.x implementation of nested cache fragments, if that would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can my latest posts list knows if any of the posts are deleted, changed or a new post is inserted?

In simple terms, they can't - the issue with caching is that you are deliberately serving old data. Sometimes that's okay, of course.

But, you can invalidate some caches. So, if you rewrite a single post, you should invalidate the cache for it, so that the next time it is viewed it re-caches with the new data. Single items like this are easy.

But if you have a cache that contains a large amount of data (say the cached versions of a paginated screen, like *Latest Posts*, one cache item per page) then it is often too awkward/slow to update a single table row within it. If so, then it might be better to serve this screen uncached. But if Latest Posts just contains the last 10 items, invalidate the whole cache for that and redraw it.

You *could* have the cached copy of this page contain a cached item for each table row (i.e. several cached rows in a larger cached table); however, the smaller your cache area, the less benefit you get. But that would certainly make it easier to invalidate just one row on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments:

> Sakuraba, it’s backed into Active Record. `belongs_to :project, touch: true` means that the project will automatically have its updated_at updated when the todolist is.

You'd need to implement this sort of dependency system in your own setup.

Comment: i'm not using the active record pattern. Also, a post and a "latest posts list" not related like a parent-child relation ship.

Comment: I know you're not using Active Record, hence "you'll need to implement". A posts list would certainly have a "has many" relationship to individual posts. This isn't something that will just magically happen for you, you're going to have to set up logic.

Comment: can you direct me to any reading or code about how to implement this behaviour?